# Inconsistent synchronization of getter/setter attribut - sonar critical issue

Tags: java, sonarqube

I couldn't fix the following Sonar critical issue:

> Inconsistent synchronization of address; locked 60% of time

adress is a private attribut in a java class with its getter and its setter as follows:

```
private String address;
public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
}
```

have an idea how to fix it? or how can i know that address is Inconsistent synchronization ?

The rule of the issue given by sonar is :

> The fields of this class appear to be accessed inconsistently with
>   respect to synchronization.  This bug report indicates that the bug
>   pattern detector judged that
>
> The class contains a mix of locked and unlocked accesses, At least one
>   locked access was performed by one of the class's own methods, and The
>   number of unsynchronized field accesses (reads and writes) was no more
>   than one third of all accesses, with writes being weighed twice as
>   high as reads A typical bug matching this bug pattern is forgetting to
>   synchronize one of the methods in a class that is intended to be
>   thread-safe.
>
> You can select the nodes labeled "Unsynchronized access" to show the
>   code locations where the detector believed that a field was accessed
>   without synchronization.
>
> Note that there are various sources of inaccuracy in this detector;
>   for example, the detector cannot statically detect all situations in
>   which a lock is held.  Also, even when the detector is accurate in
>   distinguishing locked vs. unlocked accesses, the code in question may
>   still be correct.

Comment: Try making address `volatile`? It could also be that a method using `address` *is* synchronized (or `address` is used in a synchronized block). That could be a bug because a `synchronized` method thinks it's running on its own, but address could be changed while it's running.

Comment: You should show  the code that makes synchronisation  on address

Comment: no , i didn?t use it in a synchronized block this is the point! , i used it in a POJO class, i will try with volatile

Comment: A caller isn't synchronized, is it?

Comment: what did you mean by a caller, the setter of adress? ,

Comment: i tried volatile and it works now!!

Comment: If you add `volatile` without understanding the problem and whether it is really a problem, you should comment this code with at least a `TODO` and explain why you have added the `volatile`.  If you don't do it, when someone a day would see this code and would probably not understand why a volatile modifier was added on this `String`.

Comment: Could you specify which rule is triggering this issue ? from which rule engine ?

Comment: yes actually i didn't understand the problem! , concerning the rule of the issue , you can find it on my edited post